# Help with brake rotors

Tags: brake-rotor, mini-cooper

Can I get different types of brake rotors from the front to the rear. i.e. buying drilled and slotted rotors for the front, and only drilled for the back since I have a front wheel drive car the brakes in the back are used way less and they won't get hot. I am buying specific front and rear rotors so they fit I just want to make sure its okay that I buy two different "types"

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! You can mix and match front to rear without issue, just so long as you keep them same/same on one axle. The only question I'd have is, ***to what end?*** There's many reasons *not* to run drilled rotors, mostly having to do with reducing the amount of mass which aids in cooling. There's other reasons as well. If it's just for looks or preference, then no big deal. If you're doing it for performance, there's actually reasons not to.

Comment: Ha, I was half way through writing just about the same thing. I'll add that "dimpling" rotors is popular these days. The rotor is only partly drilled through. It gives  the same look without *as much* danger of cracks and rotor failure.